# How to cancel a channel job based on an ID in golang

Tags: go

So i have a `POST` endpoint that creates a job and adds them to a chan. `workerJobsChan = make(chan Job, maxQueueSize)`

This is how i execute the jobs in the channel (`main.go`):

```
for i := 1; i <= maxWorkers; i++ {
    go func(i int) {
        for job := range workerJobsChan {
            ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
            storeJob(job.Search.ID, cancel)
            job.Execute(ctx, c.db, i)
        }
    }(i)
}
```

I store the cancel function in a map: `cancelJobFuncs = make(map[int]context.CancelFunc)`.

This is the job function :

```
func (j *Job) Execute(ctx context.Context, db *sql.DB, workerID int) error {


    for {
        select {
        // Check for cancellation signal
        case <-ctx.Done():
             if err := ctx.Err(); err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Worker", workerID, "error", err)
             }
            fmt.Println("Worker", workerID, "cancelled")
            return nil

        default:
            fmt.Printf("worker%d: processing %s\n", workerID, j.Search.Query)
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
            fmt.Printf("worker%d: active %s\n", workerID, j.Search.Query)
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
            fmt.Printf("worker%d: completed %s!\n", workerID, j.Search.Query)

        }
    }
}
```

I cancel a context like this (in a http handler):

```
cancelJob(search.ID)
```

But the job just continues to run. I tried a lot of things but i just can't seem to get it working.

Comment: By "continues on" you mean it runs the `default` case in the select block? You don't have anything which would return from the `default` case or break the `for` loop.

Comment: @JimB ctx.Done should return right? then it breaks the for and select?

Comment: Yes, but that's why I was asking what you mean by "continues on". This example works just fine, but of course that does not match your expectations because you are asking about it.

Comment: with continues on i mean, it doesn't stop the function. So it keeps on printing while it should have been stopped.

Comment: Using the same select/context pattern, you can see all goroutines return: https://go.dev/play/p/f9kSXIzALXI

Comment: Yeah, that should not happen, i edited it a little bit, so you can see it get's cancelled but the execute functions continue

Comment: You edited what? If the functions didn't get canceled, then the program could not exit.

Comment: They did get cancelled: https://go.dev/play/p/LHzXYVh5Pcl

Comment: Yes, the context cancellation worked. What is the question? I suggest adding a [mre] to the question here so we can figure out what problem it is you are trying to solve.

Comment: I'm sorry, i meant did not get cancelled. I get this:

Comment: worker0: active
worker2: active
worker1: active
worker3: active
worker4: active
Cancelling
worker2: completed!
worker4: completed!
Worker 2 error context canceled
Worker 2 cancelled
worker1: completed!
Worker 1 error context canceled
Worker 1 cancelled
worker3: completed!
Worker 3 error context canceled
Worker 3 cancelled
worker0: completed!
Worker 0 error context canceled
Worker 0 cancelled
Worker 4 error context canceled
Worker 4 cancelled

Comment: Each worker prints `Worker N cancelled`, which shows it was cancelled. If it wasn't, `main` would never return and exit the process. Refer to my very first comment, you have nothing returning from the `default` case, so you are not going to return until after the default case has finished executing.

Comment: I get what you mean, but my expectation is: jobs start to execute, 3 for example printing: processing, then they print active, now we cancel the jobs. They should stop but what happens is, they still print completed after 2 seconds after cancellation.

Comment: Your context is only checked at the point of the `<-ctx.Done()` case. Calling `cancel` doesn't magically insert a `return` into some other piece of executing code. You need to pass the context to where it needs to be checked, and check it when you want to possibly return. Seeing how you have `*sql.DB` in there, this means also using methods like `QueryContext`.

Comment: So cancelling a job (execute function) from another place in my code is basically impossible?

Comment: It's not impossible, lots of things can be canceled, that's the whole point of using a context this way. If you are using blocking functions which cannot be canceled, like `time.Sleep`, then it may mean polling for a `Done()` signal, or just unblocking the main path and letting the goroutine die later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to state an obvious point: if your code does not check `ctx.Done()`, it can't know it is cancelled.
(by the way this is yet another rewording of what @JimB wrote in comments to your question).

So when your code in your `.Execute(...)` method starts executing this block :

```
    fmt.Printf("worker%d: processing %s\n", workerID, j.Search.Query)
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("worker%d: active %s\n", workerID, j.Search.Query)
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("worker%d: completed %s!\n", workerID, j.Search.Query)
```

it will go to the end of this block (7 seconds). There is no instruction telling it to stop on cancellation.

---

If you want your function to be able to detect cancellation during the "Sleep" instructions, you have to change your code.

Here is one example of how to do that with your example:

```
func (j *Job) Execute(ctx context.Context, db *sql.DB, workerID int) error {


    for {
        fmt.Printf("worker%d: processing %s\n", workerID, j.Search.Query)

        // rewrite time.Sleep() with time.After() so that it can be composed
        // in a select statement:
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("Worker", workerID, "cancelled")
            return nil
        case <-time.After(2 * time.Second):
            // keep going
        }

        fmt.Printf("worker%d: active %s\n", workerID, j.Search.Query)

        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("Worker", workerID, "cancelled")
            return nil
        case <-time.After(5 * time.Second):
            // keep going
        }

        fmt.Printf("worker%d: completed %s!\n", workerID, j.Search.Query)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Tlpggug2AUB

I guess your actual code doesn't have `time.Sleep()` instructions but rather `processSearch(...)` or `doQuery(...)` or ...

If you need these functions to be cancellable during their execution, you will need to somehow pass your cancellation context to them and have them check the cancellation some way or some other.

One way to "pass the context" is obviously to add it to the arguments of said functions :

```
processSearch(ctx, ...)
doQuery(ctx, ...)
```

but depending on your existing code, some arguments may already have a built-in way to be cancelled.
As an illustration:

```
// an http.Request carries a context:
func doQuery(req *http.Request, ....) {
    ...
}

// at call site:
    ...
    req := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, "GET", "https://some.other.service/", nil)
    doQuery(req, ...)
```

Comment: thanks, this make a lot of sense. I'm going to do it this way: i have a main task, those have small tasks as children, i loop those childeren and for every child i check the context for cancellation.